# Are there any legal issues while extracting content from RSS feeds?

Tags: rss, legal

I would like to know whether these free SMS alert sites such as My Today SMS, Alertix pay for the sites such as religate, oneindia.in e.t.c, Or they just mention in their website that this service powered by Oneindia.

What I would like to know is whether these people pay any royalty/monthly/annual fee for these religate/oneindia, by which I also mean:

Are there any legal issues attached to extracting data from the RSS feeds these websites provide for services like free SMS alerts?

Comment: Nothing against the people who have answered, but if you want legal advice, Super User is probably not the place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer fits all.

The main reason for content owners offering RSS feeds is simply because they want to syndicate the content to people in a quick and easy way.

Generally people offer this service for end users to see the content and there should be no harm in building an application or using a feed for yourself.

If however, you are going to be references, reselling or offering someone's content to anyone, you start going in the area of copyrighted work... Look at the recent complaints about Google News for example.

I am pretty sure that if you use any content from any website, you have to agree to their terms and conditions as well as their terms of service which may prevent this sort of activity.

The only real way to know is to get in contact with the website in question and ask for their permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want your content syndicated, you wouldn't publish an RSS feed.

I'd say that allowing this syndication is one of the reasons for having an RSS feed, and to pursue legal action for someone using it would be stupid.

Comment: Thanks Rich for your answer.

But I heard from my colleagues that extracting data from feeds can be considered illegal, unless I take the required approvals. Though I'm not sure whether my view[what I have mentioned here] is correct.

If any more opinions are there, they are most welcome

Comment: In the question I asked, The free SMS alert websites are making money out of these feeds which is commercial, If you have any more opinions, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no Such Legal issue.

Feel Free to extract them and use them Where ever you want to use or do whatever you want to do with them.

Giving RSS means the Publisher wishes RSS as frequently updated data.

Just to get the incoming links / Repearing visitors.

And there are tons of tools that fetch data.Safari/Firefox/Opera/.. Have built-in features.
Yahoo fetches them...